# How to use React.js and Node.js on the same repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-server

I've recently been having trouble with this. Is it possible to have reactjs and Parse Server(not the SDK) running and taking requests in the same node project?

If so, how?

Comment: could you provide more contexts of the trouble you have?

Comment: Its not really a trouble but, I was wondering, if I wanted to create a web app using parse server and react. Can I install both of them to make it like a MERN application or do I have to put the parse server in another node.js project and the react app in another project? Please feel free to tell me if I'm not making sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

You can use `yarn workspaces` to share some packages between theses two project

You have to create two different workspaces, one for the frontend and another for the backend

Here is more information about [it](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). They have a really nice documentation

Comment: Thanks dude. You have really helped me here. I would vote but I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: No problen :)  glad that you found a solution

Comment: @Kelvin haha I voted for Julien Kode on your behalf :>